# how to come back to my application after ACTION_CALL in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got one question regarding the intent action `ACTION_CALL`.

What is the correct way of getting back to the own application/activity after the user ends the call?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +m1));

startActivity(intent);
```

I have made the call using the above code. Please provide me with a solution to call my own activity after the call action.

Comment: doesn't it just come back when you end the call?

Comment: If for some reason it does not just come back to the last activity, try using startActivityForResult(intent, 0).

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately some phones have settings to force going into for example the Call Log after a call...

However, you can run a loop after your `startActivity` to check  `TelephonyManager.getCallState`, and when it's again `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`, you can restart your own `Activity`

be sure to add some sleep to the loop

Answer (score 0):

AFter the endofcall.......it just had to come back to the activity..!! you can handle that one `onRestart();`

Answer (score 0):

I run with the same problem, and ended up solving it like this:

1. Make a Callback interface with single (or multiple if you want)
   methods
2. Implement that interface in your activity
3. Make a reference to that interface inside PhoneStateListener class
4. Call a method within that interface when the call ended

---

```
public class CallTracker extends PhoneStateListener implements Runnable {
  private Context mActivity;
  private Callback mCallback;

  public interface Callback {
    void onCallEnded();
  }

  public CallTracker(Activity activity) {
    super();
    mActivity = activity;

    if (mActivity instanceof Callback) {
      mCallback = (Callback) mActivity;
    }
  }

  @Override public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
         mCallback.onCallEnded();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CallerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    CallTracker.Callback {

    @Override public void onCallEnded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Call ended!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```